# How to test internal controllers without route in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, testing

I am trying to reduce redundant code by refactoring template and controller code into reusable components, which I then use via the `render(controller('AppBundle:Foo/Bar:baz'))` construct inside my other templates.

Of course I would like to test these components. In the examples regarding functional testing, however, an actual route is required to make fake test requests. But my `BarController` here is purely internal and has no routes attached to it. How can I test this controller?

Creating dummy routes is not always possible, because some of the arguments are model objects that cannot be passed via URL. Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service approach sounds nice, but I am simply doing this now:

```
self::$kernel->getContainer()->get('router')->getContext()->setParameter('_locale', 'en');

$controller = new MyController();
$controller->setContainer(self::$kernel->getContainer());

$response = $controller->myAction($arg1, $arg2, $argWhatever);

// assertions here
```

Seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the controllers are setup as services, then they can be easily tested much as any other class would be unit-tested. Even before Symfony 3.3 started to make them services by default, I had altered some of my own to allow them to be more easily tested like this.

Comment: That's an option, or even if they are not registered as a service, in a functional tests you should be able to build them & inject them the container (from your functional test client's kernel)

Comment: How do you properly set up the environment if there is no actual request? Specifically, I'm getting a Twig error when generating a route URL, because the `_locale` parameter is missing